# How can I fix 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv' issue?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys # keys içerisinden enter yapabilmesini sağlıyoruz
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/SCRAPE/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
import pandas as pd
browser.get("http://event.ybu.edu.tr/kulupler/") 
import csv

#browser.fullscreen_window()
#time.sleep(2)


#for i in range(6): 
    #browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)') #sayfayı aşağıya doğru çekmek için
    #time.sleep(1)

Kulup_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div") #ilk kulüp için sonra değiştir
Kulup_button.click()    
time.sleep(1)

for i in range(1): 
    browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)') #sayfayı aşağıya doğru çekmek için
    time.sleep(1)


kulupnames = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
kulupList=[]
for kulupname in kulupnames:
    kulupList.append(kulupname.text)  

mails = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.bg-orange.btn-social")
MailList=[]
for mail in mails:
    MailList.append(mail.text)
    
    
FacebookAdresses = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.bg-blue.btn-social") 
FacebookList=[] 
for FacebookAdress in FacebookAdresses: 
   FacebookList.append(FacebookAdress.text)    
    
TwitterAdresses = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.btn-social.bg-aqua") 
TwitterList=[] 
for TwitterAdress in TwitterAdresses: 
   TwitterList.append(TwitterAdress.text) 
   
   
InstagramAdresses = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.btn-social.bg-light-blue") 
InstagramList=[] 
for InstagramAdress in InstagramAdresses:
   InstagramList.append(InstagramAdress.text)
   

AkademikDanismanlar = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
DanismanList=[] 
for AkademikDanisman in AkademikDanismanlar: 
   DanismanList.append(AkademikDanisman.text)      

KulupBaskanlari = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")
BaskanList=[] 
for KulupBaskani in KulupBaskanlari: 
   BaskanList.append(KulupBaskani.text)  

ToplamUyeler = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")
UyeList=[] 
for Uye in ToplamUyeler: 
   UyeList.append(Uye.text)  

Etkinlikler = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")
EtkinlikList=[] 
for Etkinlik in Etkinlikler: 
   EtkinlikList.append(Etkinlik.text)  


time.sleep(5)

browser.quit()


DataFile = csv.writer(open('AYBU.csv','w'))
DataFile.writerow(['KulupAdi','MailAdresi','FacebookAdresi','TwitterAdresi','InstagramAdres','AkademikDanisman','KulupBaskani','ToplamUyeSayisi','ToplamEtkinlikSayisi'])
DataFile.to_csv("AYBU.csv", index = False, encoding='utf-8-sig')


liste = ['kulupList','MailList','FacebookList','TwitterList','InstagramList','DanismanList','BaskanList','UyeList','EtkinlikList']

df = pd.DataFrame(data = liste)
liste.to_csv("AYBU.csv", index = False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

I am trying to save my variable list as dataframe to csv.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple flaws in your code that I can see.

I took your code and made it work and I'll explain how:

```
import csv
import time

import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  # keys içerisinden enter yapabilmesini sağlıyoruz

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(5)
browser.get("http://event.ybu.edu.tr/kulupler/")
Kulup_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div") #ilk kulüp için sonra değiştir
Kulup_button.click()
time.sleep(1)

for _ in range(1): 
    browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)') #sayfayı aşağıya doğru çekmek için
    time.sleep(1)


kulupnames = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
kulupList = [kulupname.text for kulupname in kulupnames]
mails = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.bg-orange.btn-social")
MailList = [mail.text for mail in mails]
FacebookAdresses = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.bg-blue.btn-social")
FacebookList = [FacebookAdress.text for FacebookAdress in FacebookAdresses]
TwitterAdresses = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.btn-social.bg-aqua")
TwitterList = [TwitterAdress.text for TwitterAdress in TwitterAdresses]
InstagramAdresses = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.btn-social.bg-light-blue")
InstagramList = [InstagramAdress.text for InstagramAdress in InstagramAdresses]
AkademikDanismanlar = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
DanismanList = [
    AkademikDanisman.text for AkademikDanisman in AkademikDanismanlar
]

KulupBaskanlari = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")
BaskanList = [KulupBaskani.text for KulupBaskani in KulupBaskanlari]
ToplamUyeler = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")
UyeList = [Uye.text for Uye in ToplamUyeler]
Etkinlikler = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")
EtkinlikList = [Etkinlik.text for Etkinlik in Etkinlikler]
time.sleep(5)

browser.quit()


with open('AYBU.csv','w') as datafile:
    DataFile = csv.writer(datafile)
    DataFile.writerow(['KulupAdi','MailAdresi','FacebookAdresi','TwitterAdresi','InstagramAdres','AkademikDanisman','KulupBaskani','ToplamUyeSayisi','ToplamEtkinlikSayisi'])

liste = [kulupList,MailList,FacebookList,TwitterList,InstagramList,DanismanList,BaskanList,UyeList,EtkinlikList]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = liste)
df.to_csv("AYBU.csv", index = False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

The key changes here are at the bottom (don't mind the clean up of the generators).

```
DataFile = csv.writer(open('AYBU.csv','w'))
DataFile.writerow(['KulupAdi','MailAdresi','FacebookAdresi','TwitterAdresi','InstagramAdres','AkademikDanisman','KulupBaskani','ToplamUyeSayisi','ToplamEtkinlikSayisi'])
DataFile.to_csv("AYBU.csv", index = False, encoding='utf-8-sig')


liste = ['kulupList','MailList','FacebookList','TwitterList','InstagramList','DanismanList','BaskanList','UyeList','EtkinlikList']

df = pd.DataFrame(data = liste)
liste.to_csv("AYBU.csv", index = False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

This code doesnt work.

```
with open('AYBU.csv','w') as datafile:
    DataFile = csv.writer(datafile)
    DataFile.writerow(['KulupAdi','MailAdresi','FacebookAdresi','TwitterAdresi','InstagramAdres','AkademikDanisman','KulupBaskani','ToplamUyeSayisi','ToplamEtkinlikSayisi'])

liste = [kulupList,MailList,FacebookList,TwitterList,InstagramList,DanismanList,BaskanList,UyeList,EtkinlikList]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = liste)
df.to_csv("AYBU.csv", index = False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

You had 'list' as strings.

pandas is able to use .to_csv but csv.writer is not.